# MySQL Workbench & Google Compute Engine Connection

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have mysql installed in an instance of google compute engine. I am able to connect to it via the shell however I want to use the MySQL workbench.

Is it possible to connect to it? I cant seem to make a connection.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if your shell is run local on host via ssh, so it's just a guess that your mysql Server is just accepting connections from localhost.

To change this open your my.cnf File (on Debian Systems saved in /etc/mysql/my.cnf) and comment the folloing Line:

change:

```
bind-address              =127.0.0.1
```

to:

```
#bind-address              =127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Be sure also to allow root connection from outside, modifying MySQL user table :

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

Comment: I had to do this too. Thank you for further expanding.

Answer (score 0):

SOehl's answer can be correct, however I did not comment. Instead i changed it to bind-address 0.0.0.0.

Comment: Same as you would comment the row. In my test enviroments i do comment :)